# Reading Strings for Key

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a few paragraphs of texts that I would like to put into my app's `NSTextView`. The problem now is my way of storing them. Since there is a lot of text, I don't want to code them into `NSString` in my code so I want to acess them through a **Plist**, a **.strings**, or a **RTF** file. I am not sure which one is better to use. My requirements are

**(1)** Able to store large amounts of texts without lagging while I copy and paste in the process.

**(2)** I need to be able to access them through a "key" for each group of word from my code.
Sorry, I have only tried Plist for now but the lagging occurs when I copy my text into each key. Is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**large amount of texts** if it is really large you should go for core-data.

If it is maintainable say few megabytes then you can go for plist.

Or you can create a data file there you can save your string as NSData.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me any link that teaches how to save strings as NSData?

Comment: @user1927992: Saving a string as NSData would be simply saving it as a plain text file. You can either use `writeToURL:atomically:encoding:error:`, or actually create an NSData using `dataUsingEncoding:` and then tell that to write itself somewhere. Either way, the result is a plain text file, suitable for naming with the .txt extension.

Comment: Then where do I put the plain text file or do I just create new file in my application?

Comment: @user1927992: The application can't put files within itself. If your application is generating this text, you should put it wherever the user told you to when you ran a Save panel or received a drag to a path control. (If the app is document-based, then that would generally be inside the document, assuming your document type is a kind of bundle or package.) If you're generating this text to include in your application, put the text file into your project directory, add it to your project, and add it to the target in a Copy Bundle Resources or Copy Files phase.